# Action is far too fast

Tags: rigging

I assigned an action from one file to another on the same character but the animation is twice the speed of the original! 24 fps but way too fast not sure why this is happening.

never seen this before. tried belnder 3.3 and 3.6 same thing. Any ideas please?

i have assigned the action from one file to another but no good